# Making Html Form Input field to remain unchange on submission

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Making Html Form Input field to remain unchange on submission.
When i submit the form, the form inputs for ball and comments gets reset to empty.

Now what i want is when i submit the form, the values in the inputs select field for ball remains unreset while comments fields values will reset 
as usual. any help below is the working code

```
    $('body').on("click",".addComment",function(){

        var element = $(this);
        var id = element.attr("id");

        $('#commentBox'+id).slideToggle(200);
        $('#comment'+id).focus();
        $('#comment'+id).val('');
        $('#comment'+id).attr("placeholder", "Write a message..");


    });



    $('body').on("click",".comBtn",function(){

        var element = $(this);
        var cid = element.attr("id");

         var ball=$('#ball').val();



        var comment=$('#comment').val();
        var datasend = 'com='+ comment + '&pid=' + cid +'&ball='+ball;


        if(comment==""){

            $('#comment'+cid).focus();
            $('#comment'+cid).attr("placeholder", "Enter the comment..");

        }else{

        $.ajax({

            type:"POST",
            url:"comment.php",
            data:datasend,
            cache:false,
            success:function(html){
                $('#loadcomment'+cid).append(html);
                $('#comment').val('');

                                 $('#ball').val('');


            }

        });

        }

        return false;

        });






<form action="" method="post">


<select name="ball" id="ball">
<option>none</option>
<option value="left">left</option>
<option value="right">right</option>
</select>

<input name="comment"  id="comment"  type="text">


<input id="comBtn"  type="submit"/>



</form>
```

Comment: On the success of your `$.ajax` call, remove the `$('#ball').val('')` line so that it doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

I am simply moving this to an answer because I put it in as a comment thinking there might be more ...

On the success of your `$.ajax` call, remove the `$('#ball').val('')` line so that it doesn't change.

Basically, the `val` statement has two purposes.

1. As `.val("123")`: this will change the value of the element to 123, an assignment.
2. As `.val()`: this will obtain the value from the element without changing it.

As you wrote it, the `$('#ball').val('')` code resets ball's value to an empty string.

Comment: I don't think they the op understand what `.val('');` does. can you explain it to him

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to this will be:
You can resetting the select dropdown using $('#ball').val(0);

I can see few issues in the code, first of all you need to wrap the entire block with

```
  $(function() {
  // your code goes here
  });
```

Second thing take advantage of HTML5 by adding the necessary attributes like required="required" and placholder on your inputs and adding novalidate on the form like the following:

```
<form method="post" novalidate>
    <input type="text"
           required="required"
           placeholder="Your placeholder goes here"/>
```

Use e.preventDefault(); to prevent the form from being submitted cause you are posting using ajax.and use only submit event

```
$('form').on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); 
 // your other functions
});
```

Put the action on the form attribute instead of the js variable, html is cheaper to manage.

```
<form action="comment.php">
```

Then in the js 
    url: $('form').attr('action'),
Of course better save it in a variable then pass it but this is just an example

Use $('form').serialize(); instead of constructing the data your self

```
`data:datasend, // bad
`data: $('form').serialize() // good
```

[Form serialize jquery api](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)